# Split controllers into separate files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had an angular setup that looked like this:

```
var dashboard = angular.module('Dashboard', ["ngRoute", "highcharts-ng"]);

dashboard.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/route1', {
            templateUrl: 'route1.html',
            controller: 'DefaultCtrl'
        });
    })
.controller('DefaultCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, settings){
    function($scope, $rootScope, $http, settings){
        $http.get("http://admin.gmserver.net/games/all?userId=" + settings.userId).success(function(data){
            $scope.games = data;
            $rootScope.gameId = "";
            $rootScope.gameName = "";
            $rootScope.apiName = "";
            $rootScope.$broadcast("loaded");
        });
    }
})
```

And this worked. I then tried to split them up into multiple files (one for each controller), and now it looks like this:

module file:

```
angular.module('Dashboard', ["ngRoute", "highcharts-ng"]);

angular.module('Dashboard').config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/route1', {
            templateUrl: 'route1.html',
            controller: 'DefaultCtrl'
        });
    }
])
```

controller file:

```
angular.module('Dashboard').controller("DefaultCtrl", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'settings',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $http, settings){
        $http.get("http://admin.gmserver.net/games/all?userId=" + settings.userId).success(function(data){
            $scope.games = data;
            $rootScope.gameId = "";
            $rootScope.gameName = "";
            $rootScope.apiName = "";
            $rootScope.$broadcast("loaded");
        });
    }
]);
```

Now when I load the page I get this:

[image: Aw, Snap]

I am loading the files like this:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="/media/js/highcharts-ng.min.js"></script>
<!-- Begin app code -->
<script src="/admin/Dashboard.js"></script>
<!-- Built with smarty -->
<script>
    angular.module('Dashboard').value("settings", {
        userId: "{$userId}",
        secret: "{$secret}"
    });
</script>
<script src="/admin/components/default/DefaultController.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/components/game/GameController.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/components/leaderboard/LeaderboardController.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/components/newsFeed/NewsFeedController.js"></script>
```

I do notice that commenting out one of the following stops the Aw, Snap error.

- `DefaultController.js` file
- Inline JavaScript
- `highcharts-ng.min.js` file

## Edit:

I changed the name of the module to my site's name and made the `Dashboard` a dependency like this:

```
angular.module('GMServer', ["ngRoute", "highcharts-ng", "Dashboard"]);
angular.module('Dashboard')
```

This fixes the "Aw, Snap" issue, but now I get this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=Dashboard

Comment: what is the error that you are getting in the console? have you included your controller file in your index.html?

Comment: I can't open the console, it locks up

Comment: Are you loading the controller file with a `<script>` tag? I doubt that'd cause this, but just to rule it out.

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment because I had started writing it before you added the HTML code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you change the userId and secret to something else without brackets or $. Like `userId: "asdf"`

Comment: that gets replaced on the backend, before the javascript even runs. It's output is basically that.

Comment: Looks like you've got an extra closing script tag on the line. That may cause it? Although it's not for me.

Comment: I am seeing that there is a conflict of some sort between the `highcharts-ng` and my `DefaultCtrl`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what happens when you call the same `angular.module` several times but I would avoid it.

You want to save the module globally so then you can reference it in different files instead of calling `angular.module('Dashboard')` each time:

```
    window.Dashboard = angular.module('Dashboard', ["ngRoute", "highcharts-ng"]);

    window.Dashboard.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
            $routeProvider.when('/route1', {
                templateUrl: 'route1.html',
                controller: 'DefaultCtrl'
            });
        }
    ])
```

and

```
    window.Dashboard.controller("DefaultCtrl", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'settings',
        function($scope, $rootScope, $http, settings){
            $http.get("http://admin.gmserver.net/games/all?userId=" + settings.userId).success(function(data){
                $scope.games = data;
                $rootScope.gameId = "";
                $rootScope.gameName = "";
                $rootScope.apiName = "";
                $rootScope.$broadcast("loaded");
            });
        }
    ]);
```

You'll just need to make sure your `<script>` tags are included in the correct order.

Avoid polluting the window object though, you may wanna namespace everything under `window.App` or use someting like requireJS or Browserify.

---

**Edit**

It's perfectly safe to retrieve a module like the OP is doing as pointed out @Sunil and [documented here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)

Comment: It's perfectly safe to call `angular.module('myModuleName')` many times. That is the intended way of retrieving the module. It's [documented here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval).

Comment: Well, that's good to know. You never know with Angular :). Thanks!

Comment: You *do* know with angular, it's documented. Also, the code is free to view, so it's not like it's a secret.